# How to get select2 multiple selection value in one object

Tags: javascript, object, jquery-select2, multi-select

I used one text box and 1 select2 multiselect dropdown box.

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal inviteuser_row" name="inviteuser_row" id="inviteuser_row">
  <input class='form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix' name='fullname' id='fullname1' placeholder='Enter Full Name' type='text'>
  <select class='bs-select2 form-control Selectelement' multiple="multiple" id='Selectelement' name='Selectelement'>
     <option value="" id="sa" >--- Select value ---</option>
     <option value="one" id="one">one</option>
     <option value="two" id="two" >two</option>
     <option value="three" id="three">three</option>
     <option value="four" id="four">four</option>
     <option value="five" id="five">five</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn green btnSave" id="invite_user">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Js**

```
$('#invite_user').click(function(){
   var x = $('#inviteuser_row').serializeArray();
   console.log(x);
});
```

Console.log I get like this :-

```
[ Object { name="fullname", value="dfsd"},
  Object { name="Selectelement", value="one"},
  Object { name="Selectelement", value="two"}, 
  Object { name="Selectelement", value="four"}
]
```

I want **Selectelement** same name value in one object, how can I manage?

Comment: Try iterating over it

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ but select2 allow multiple value it's not possible with iterating.

Comment: Why not ? You are already showing an array

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ  But it is in diffrent object , I want it in same Object

Comment: How about getting that object and building your own from that

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I want Like this : - 
> object { name="Selectelement", value="one,two,four" }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136247/discussion-between-keyz-mist-and-ss-).

Comment: what about this `$('#Selectelement').select2('data');`